# CEdit no line breaks for MFS Control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

IN MFC, CEdit Control Multi Line

In the VC ResourceView, when I check the Properties | Styles | Multiline 
checkbox for a CEdit control. I have uncheck the horizontal scroll and vertical.

```
watch on data L"0X0V, 0Hz\r\n0W\r\n0.00A" in VS
wchar_t Data[100];
m_Data.SetWindowTextW(Data);
```

The text don't break. Just one long line. When addning the text to the member variable m_Data.

Comment: Linefeeds on Windows are generally expressed as `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.

Comment: After chaning in \r\n it still not working. Can not understand why?

Comment: Are you sure your edit isn't actually multi line ?

Comment: Can you please (hex) print the output of m_Data.GetStyle()?